# How to customize error messages in nested attributes?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

I'm trying to customize error messages. But the problem I have is that in nested attributes I get errors like `People email is invalid` or `People username can't be blank`, when all I wanted to say is `Email is invalid`.

I'm trying to customize the error messages but I don't know how to do it with nested attributes.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      person: "Person"
    attributes:
      person:
        email: "Email address"
    errors:
      models:
        person:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "is a required field."
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set up nested attributes in your `en.yml` file. The key is changing `person:` to `people:` and nesting it under the associated `belongs_to` class (replace `parent_model` with the name of the "parent" class):

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      parent_model:
        people:
          email: "Email address"
```

Note: based on this commit, it looks like the new way to do this will be as follows, however this probably won't work in anything before Rails 3.2 which is not yet released:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      "parent_model/people":
        email: "Email address"
```

Comment: The `"parent_model/people"` worked for me (Rails 4.2).. Thanks!